# Java Extend ArrayList<Dummy> functions

Tags: java, list, inheritance, arraylist

let's say I have

```
class Dummy {
    String a, b;
    public Dummy(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return a+b;
    }
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
```

}

i would like to have

```
List<Dummy> myList = new ArrayList<Dummy>() {{
     add(new Dummy("test", ""));
     add(new Dummy("boo", "o"));
}};

System.out.println( myList.toString());
System.out.println( myList.getAs());  //should return ["test", "boo"]
System.out.println( myList.getBs());//should return ["", "o"]
```

If you see what I mean

probably have to create class extending `ArrayList<Dummy>` ?

**edit:**

seems good like that

```
class Dummy {
    String a, b;
//...
    public static String toAString(List<Dummy> l){
       String s="";
       for (Dummy d : l){
           s+=d.a;
       }
       return s;
    }
}
```

**edit2:**

I will have just 2 Strings in Dummy, is it better doing a `ArrayList<String []>` rather ? in terms of memory

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: It may well be easier to write it as a method wrapping the `ArrayList` rather than extending it directly.

Comment: @Louis, you mean 2 methods: public String toAString(ArrayList<Dummy> list){ do the loop here}?

Comment: Well, either do a loop, or return some kind of view, but yeah.

Comment: @ciril, several folks have offered viable answers.  If any of them are acceptable, perhaps you could upvote and/or accept some answers.

Comment: yes tx for your answer, missingfaktor is the closer to what I search, waiting for java8 in 1 year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define first-class functions corresponding to `getA` and `getB`. I am using `Function` from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for that.

```
class Dummy {
    String a, b;
    public Dummy(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return a+b;
    }
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public static Function<Dummy, String> getA = new Function<Dummy, String>() {
      public String apply(Dummy d) {
        return d.a;
      }
    }
    public static Function<Dummy, String> getB = new Function<Dummy, String>() {
      public String apply(Dummy d) {
        return d.b;
      }
    }
}
```

This is how you can use it: (`Iterables` below is also from Guava).

```
List<Dummy> myList = new ArrayList<Dummy>() {{
     add(new Dummy("test", ""));
     add(new Dummy("boo", "o"));
}};

System.out.println( myList.toString());
System.out.println( Iterables.transform(myList, Dummy.getA)); // returns ["test", "boo"]
System.out.println( Iterables.transform(myList, Dummy.getB)); // returns ["", "o"]
```

Comment: +1 because I like the idea but it would imply to add a dependency

Comment: That's a valid concern. Luckily the required functionality is quite easy to implement yourself. (About 10 lines.)

Comment: nice, what is the meaning of Function *`<Dummy, String>`*, means it takes a Dummy and return a String?, too bad guava can't use the defaut getters for that

Comment: @ciril, yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: @ciril, thankfully, with Java 8, you won't have to define these function objects explicitly. `myList.map(Dummy::getAs)` will do the trick. `map` is a method from new collection API, and `Dummy::getAs` gives you what's called a method reference.

Comment: are you sure it will no be `myList.map(Dummy::getA)` (with no 's)?

Comment: @ciril, yeah, that's a typo. I meant `Dummy::getA`.

Answer (score 2):

In pre-Java 8, you can use one of the functional idiom APIs like Guava as follows:

```
Function<Dummy, String> getAFunc = new Function<Dummy, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Dummy dummy) {
        return dummy.getA();
    }
}

Function<Dummy, String> getBFunc = new Function<Dummy, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Dummy dummy) {
        return dummy.getB();
    }
}

System.out.println( Lists.transform(myList, getAFunc) );
System.out.println( Lists.transform(myList, getBFunc) );
```

Agreed that this is pretty ugly and verbose, and some of what the Guava team refers to when they say that [misuse of functional idioms makes them weep](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).

But wait, there's hope, and a way to make this code both more elegant, shorter, and more generalized to any situation like this, using [the open source **Funcito** library](http://funcito.googlecode.com) (**DISCLAIMER**: I am the primary author)

Now instead you can simply write

```
Function<Dummy, AType> getAFunc = functionFor( callsTo(Dummy.class).getA() );
Function<Dummy, BType> getBFunc = functionFor( callsTo(Dummy.class).getB() );

System.out.println( Lists.transform(myList, getAFunc) );
System.out.println( Lists.transform(myList, getBFunc) );
```

They key to brevity is using Funcito to compose your Functions.  It works even assuming A & B weren't Strings, as I have shown in the example.  And now you can use this for any type besides Dummy, and for any number of fields with getter methods, by using Funcito to quickly generate a Function that wraps the appropriate method.  And Funcito will also work with a few alternative functional APIs other than Guava, if you prefer.

Note that the above is using imports from Guava and static imports from Funcito.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, you need to extend ArrayList to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
      List<Dummy> myList = new ArrayList<Dummy>() 
      myList.add(new Dummy("test", ""));     
      myList.add(new Dummy("boo", "o")); 


                     for(Dummy dumdum : myList) {
                     System.out.println(dumdum.getA() + " " + dumdum.getB());
                      }
```

Is this what you are looking for, or do I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Composition instead of Inheritance..............**

**Considering all classes in same package.**

`Dummy Class:`

```
class Dummy {
    String a, b;
    public Dummy(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return a+b;
    }
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

`Test Class:`  **EDITED**

```
public class Test{
 Test t = new Test();                   
 List<Dummy> myList = new ArrayList<Dummy>();
 public static void main(String[] args){
 t.myList.add(new Dummy("test", ""));
 t.myList.add(new Dummy("boo", "o"));
for (Dummy d : t.myList)
{
  System.out.println(d.toString());
  System.out.println(d.getA());  
  System.out.println(d.getB()); 
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Now try it out...... Its working as you wanted it to be... sorry for the mistake...

Comment: yes do the same thing, I needed a function to call from the *myList*, the thing is I will call these function many times, so many times it will do this loop..

Answer (score 0):

Extending ArrayList quickly becomes untenable, as you'll eventually need a MoronArrayList, a GeniusArrayList, a DummyHashMap, a DummyQueue etc...

The Guava stuff suggested by @missingfaktor is one option.  Another option, if this is really needed often, it to put utility methods in the *Dummy* class.  e.g.

```
public static String toAStrings(Collection<Dummy> collection) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;
   boolean firstTime = true;
   for (Dummy dummy : collection) {
      if (!firstTime )
         sb.append(",");
      firstTime = false;
      sb.append(dummy.getA());
   }

   return sb.toString();
}
```